# Necessity to grant privileges on schema public + not working after the priveleges have been granted

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

Under postgres user:

```
postgres=# GRANT ALL ON schema public TO trololo;
GRANT


postgres=# \dn+
                                       List of schemas
  Name  |       Owner       |           Access privileges            |      Description       
--------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+------------------------
 public | pg_database_owner | pg_database_owner=UC/pg_database_owner+| standard public schema
        |                   | =U/pg_database_owner                  +| 
        |                   | trololo=UC/pg_database_owner           | 
(1 row)


postgres=# \l
                                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | ICU Locale | Locale Provider |   Access privileges    
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+------------------------
 marketing | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | =Tc/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres +
           |          |          |             |             |            |                 | marketing=CTc/postgres
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | =c/postgres           +
           |          |          |             |             |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | =c/postgres           +
           |          |          |             |             |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
 trololo   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | =Tc/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres +
           |          |          |             |             |            |                 | trololo=CTc/postgres
```

Under trololo user:

```
michael@michael:~$ psql -U trololo
Password for user trololo: 
psql (15.2 (Ubuntu 15.2-1.pgdg20.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

trololo=> create table trololo_entity (id int8 not null, trololo varchar(255), primary key (id));
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: create table trololo_entity (id int8 not null, trololo varch...
                     ^
trololo=>
```

I want to find out the following:

1. Why do I still get the error message if I have granted the privileges?
2. I faced this problem after upgrading PostgreSQL from 12 to 15. If I'm not mistaken, for 12th there was no need to grant privileges on schema public. I just granted privileges on the table and that's all. Why should I grant permissions on this schema as well as on the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the permissions in database `postgres`, but you are trying to create the table in database `trololo` (look at the `psql` prompt). Since you didn't grant the permissions in database `trololo` the attempt to create the table fails.

You are probably misled by `psql`'s defaults: if you don't specify the database explicitly, for example with the `-d` option, `psql` will connect to the database with the same name as the database user.

Comment: I have changed my question. I have granted permissions on the database. Could you tell me what should I do now?

Comment: So what? Granting permissions on the database doesn't affect the permissions on a schema in the database. You'll have to connect to `trololo` and change the permissions on the schema.